# Selenium WebDriver throws org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException while running test cases in parallel using testNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

While running test cases in parallel using TestNG "UnreachableBrowserException" is throwing whereas if parallel="false" is given test cases are executing succesfully.

TestNG Version: 6.9.10
Selenium Java: 3.0.1
Chrome Version: 58.0.3029.110
Chrome Driver Version: 2.29

TestNG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2" verbose="5">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testscripts.LoginScenario.ParallelTwo"/>
      <class name="testscripts.LoginScenario.ParallelOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**TESTNG FAILURE EXCEPTION**

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'A5***-**-00**', ip: '10.43.***.**', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

**CONSOLE**

```
TestNG 6.9.10 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)

FAILED: mail
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'

FAILED: google
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'A5DA', ip: '10.**.***.**', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
```

Please clarify!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the browser are you using for testing

Comment: Try update Chromedriver and Chrome. How You set up chromedriver path ?

Comment: plz provide code. how your are initializing the driver?